# Can too many text messages and phone calls cancel out your alarm?

Tags: sms, hardware, alarm

I was blamed for canceling a friend's alarm clock from half a country away and recently I wondered if it was even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that with my phone. I created an alarm for 1 min and I gave a call to my phone. During call it vibrated for alarm, and when I cancelled my call it was still vibrating, notifying me of my alarm.